# Allow star only once and not allow it not to be mixed with any other

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regex. i want to validate like `abcd,*,acd123` etc. I dont want * to be mixed with any like abc* and it should be allowed only once ex following should be rejected `** or *,*`

```
/^([A-Za-z\d\/\*]+(,[A-Za-z\d\/\*]+)*)?$/.test(v)
```

valid:

```
ADSAD,*,adsad
*,adsds,asd123
```

Invalid:

```
**,asads
sasd,*,asa,*
```

Comment: Could you please share strings that should match and those where no match should be found?

Comment: Do you actually want to fail match if a star is not wrapped by comas?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Put the `*` out of the character classes and only allow it as an alternative to the alphanumeric or `/` symbols:

```
/^(?!.*\*.*\*)(?:(?:\*|[A-Za-z\d\/]+)(?:,(?:[A-Za-z\d\/]+|\*))*)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LkJCG/4)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\*.*\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match once there are 2 `*` symbols in the string
- `(?:(?:\*|[A-Za-z\d\/]+)(?:,(?:[A-Za-z\d\/]+|\*))*)?` - an optional group (the whole string can be empty) matching:

  - `(?:\*|[A-Za-z\d\/]+)` - a `*` (`\*`) or (`|`) 1 or more alphanumeric or `/` symbols (`[A-Za-z\d\/]+`), then followed with
  - `(?:,(?:[A-Za-z\d\/]+|\*))*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `,` - a comma
    - `(?:[A-Za-z\d\/]+|\*)` -  1 or more alphanumeric or `/` symbols or a `*`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: * at beginning is returning as false

Comment: I updated the regex to meet this requirement, matching all the valid and not matching all the invalid sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will solve your whole problem, but the posted question can be solved this way:

```
^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$
```

where

- `^` is the start of the string;
- `[^*]` is any character that is *not* an asterisk.

  - Since we have `[^*]*,`, it means any number of characters that are not asterisks, followed by a comma;
  - `([^*]*,)?` means we have zero or at most one of these in the string.
- `\*` is the asterisk char. Since it is a special one, we need to escape it with `\`;
- Again, we have `([^*]*,)?
- `$` means the end of the string.

Here is the result:

```
> /^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$/.test('abc,*,def')
true
> /^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$/.test('abc,def')
false
> /^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$/.test('abc,*,def,*,a')
false
> /^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$/.test('abc,*')
true
> /^([^*]*,)?\*(,[^*]*)?$/.test('*,abc')
true
```